# Can I set registered Custom Taxonomy For my Custom Post Type in code?

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I registered Custom Taxonomy through Custom Post Type UI Plugin and assigned them for my CPT Advertisements.

When I add new Advertisement through function() after submit my form, I know set all I need (title, custom_fields...) but can I set already defined some of custom taxonomies for my new Post? I know to do that in wp-admin ... but I had to set it in code, when I choose one of the custom taxonomies from the selectbox...

Custom taxonomies assigned to my Custom Post Type:

[image]

Set Custom taxonomy through selectbox:

```
<select name="taxonomy-market-type" class="custom-select" id="taxonomy-category">
                        <?php
                        $terms = get_terms( array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'advertisement_category',
                            'hide_empty' => false) );
                        ?>
                        <option value="" hidden>Choose category</option>
                        <?php foreach ($terms as $term) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $term->slug ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
   </select>
```

Function, where I add New Custom Post Type:

```
function addAdvertisement() {
    header('Content-Type: application/html;charset=utf-8');
    $uploadDir = wp_upload_dir();

    // Create post object
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $_POST['name'],
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type' => 'advertisements'
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post);



    if(isset($POST['category'])) {
        // add custom taxonomy here

    }

    // Insert the post into the database
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'nazov_inzeratu', $_POST['name']);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'popis_inzeratu', $_POST['description']);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'fotka', implode(',', $uploadedImages));
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'id_inzerat', $post_id);

    echo get_permalink($post_id);


    wp_die();
}
```

Is that even possible, please? Thanks for the advices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to assign custom taxonomies to custom post types by calling `wp_set_post_terms()` as follows.

```
if(isset($POST['category'])) {
    $adv_cat = array($POST['category']);
    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $adv_cat, 'advertisement_category');
}
```

I hope this will work.
Please have a look at [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms) codex page for further info.

Comment: Yes,you are absolutely right, I have already solved this with a similar way but thanks anyway :)